# Setting Doctrine attributes in a task

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I'm trying to set a Doctrine attribute in a task, but it doesn't seem to work.

What I'm trying to set, is an attribute to disable Doctrine validation:

```
$databaseManager = new sfDatabaseManager($this->configuration);
$connection = $databaseManager->getDatabase('doctrine')->getConnection();
$connection->setAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_VALIDATE, Doctrine_Core::VALIDATE_NONE);
```

But it doesn't work, because I'm creating a new record with a value that doesn't validate because of a minlength rule, and it displays a validation error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you paste your error message?

Comment: which version of doctrine? or symfony? I had problems with 1.4.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set it on the manager:

```
$databaseManager->setAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_VALIDATE, Doctrine_Core::VALIDATE_NONE)
```